# How to retrieve a public key from remote host?

Tags: ssh, php, openssh, public-key

I received from a partner an SSH private key also, I need to make a php script to connect to the host and send some data through this connexion.

However I need to provide to the ssh php function a public key, but the partner didn't send me the public key.

How can I get from the remote host the public key in a separate file?

Any advices?

Comment: If you are connecting from an application to a remote host, you need access to the private key to authenticate to the remote host, the public key will not help you authenticate (if it did, and was public, then anyone could authenticate to the host). http://inside.mines.edu/~gmurray/HowTo/sshNotes.html

Answer (score 4):

If you have the private key you can generate the public key from it using `ssh-keygen -i`, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: This is correct although the question is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a key for a specific user? If so, and you have access to the server, it would be something like `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.